Laravel mPDF mail attachment error "Illuminate\Mail\Attachment::fromData(): Argument #1 ($data) must be of type Closure, string given"
Hi I'm trying make a function to send an email and attach a .pdf file by using the dependency laravel mPDF
My mail object where the error happends is in the attachments() function:
class TIPoliciesMail extends Mailable
{
  // ...
  public function attachments(): array
  {
     $pdf = pdf::loadView('pdf.basics.ti-policies-pdf');
      return [
         Attachment::fromData($pdf->output(), 'doc.pdf')->withMime('application/pdf')
      ];
  }
  // ...
}

This is the error message
Error image message
I want to know what's a Closure type because the error tells, that is because a string is given instead of a Closure, I don't know if the error occurs in the function $pdf->output()

By default output() will return inline pdf content so you should return string from the pdf output like
$pdf->Output('', 'S');

And in your code it should be
Attachment::fromData($pdf->output('', 'S'), 'doc.pdf')->withMime('application/pdf')

Reference: MPDF - E-mail a PDF file

I've try the function with the attribute output('', 'S') but it doesn't work becase the function itself don't allow attributes, and by the default the function returns a string (return $this->mpdf->Output('', Destination::STRING_RETURN);)
